# Including variables in jekyll from given file

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I want to have my variable assignments placed in a single txt file or similar in jekyll, and have them included in my Front Matter for assignment. So instead of this:

```
---
variable1: abc
variable2: 123
---
```

I can have this:

```
---
{% include variables.txt %}  
---
```

The purpose of this is to have a website that is editable by a technologically inexperienced client. I want to abstract out the core site structure from the things that need to be edited as much as possible - without setting up a CMS, or moving into a dynamic site (so it can still be hosted on github pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just throw all of your variables into your `_config.yml` file and then they can be accessed like this:

```
{{ site.variable1 }}
```

Comment: This is what I did. But I want a better way!